# MainViewController (storyboard) can not push my UITableViewController

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, uitableview, storyboard

I just created a new project in xcode 4.2 with template Utility Application. This is my project hierarchy:

[image]

Then, I tried to push UITableViewController without XIB files (Batikla : UITableViewController) from MainViewController.
First I put a button in my MainViewController storyboard and wired it to my ibaction method:

```
@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize flipsidePopoverController = _flipsidePopoverController;

    - (IBAction)batikla{
        NSLog(@"test 1");

        Batikla *batikla = [[Batikla alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        batikla.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:batikla animated:YES];
        [batikla release];

        NSLog(@"test 2");

}
```

After tapping the button there is no view pushed to the view, instead in the console appears:

```
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Attaching to process 58916.
2012-01-17 01:30:47.569 iBadah[58916:207] test 1
2012-01-17 01:30:47.572 iBadah[58916:207] test 2
```

The method was fired but why didn't my uitableviewcontroller get pushed into the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push and pop require a navigation controller. The utility template does not include a navigation controller.

Comment: How do i put navigation controller in the storyboard? i went to editor  -> embed in -> navigation controller then ran it, i got error like this: [UINavigationController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a20820. what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

yeah, i got it..
TJ was rite, i missing navigation controller here
so here it goes:
in AppDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, i commented out the default code, and put with navigation view controller, check this out: (as i used utility template, i assume u got the same code as well)

```
// Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    MainViewController *controller = (MainViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    //MainViewController *controller = (MainViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
```

and dont forget to add uinavcontroller in the storyboard, u can do it from --> editor -> embed in -> navigation controller (after click mainview controller), like this:
[image]
and u shd good to go there.

Hope this help someone.
Thanks